# PostGIS St_Contains does not return data

Tags: postgis

I have written the following example to to find if a point is within the polygon.

```
CREATE TABLE points_of_interest(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name varchar(50),
    lat numeric,
    lon numeric,
    geom geometry(POINT,4326));

CREATE TABLE papakura_places(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name varchar(50),
  lat numeric,
  lon numeric,geom geometry(POINT,4326));

insert into papakura_places(name, lat, lon) values ('a', -37.066337, 174.940995);
insert into papakura_places(name, lat, lon) values ('b',-37.067518, 174.940872);
insert into papakura_places(name, lat, lon) values ('d',-37.067334, 174.938968);
insert into papakura_places(name, lat, lon) values ('d', -37.066154, 174.939110);
insert into points_of_interest(name, lat, lon) values ('pointOfInterest', -37.066486, 174.939657);
insert into points_of_interest(name, lat, lon) values ('noPointOfInterest', -37.061010, 174.943166);

UPDATE papakura_places SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326);
UPDATE points_of_interest SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326);

select * from papakura_places;
select * from points_of_interest where name like 'pointOfInterest';

select distinct * from papakura_places,points_of_interest ;

SELECT points_of_interest.*
FROM  points_of_interest, papakura_places
WHERE ST_intersects(points_of_interest.geom, papakura_places.geom);
```

I have verified the two points on the google maps. one is inside and one is outside.  So the result should return something. But not sure why its not returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `papakura_places` table has point geom. `ST_Contains` will not return true when points of interest lie within the four points in the table.

Instead, make a polygon with the `papakura_places` points, and use that with ST_Contains:

```
WITH papakura_places_polygon AS (
    SELECT
        ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(geom)) AS geom
    FROM
        ((select * from papakura_places) union all (select * from papakura_places limit 1)) a
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    points_of_interest poi
    JOIN
    papakura_places_polygon ppp ON ST_Contains(ppp.geom, poi.geom);
```